# unwanted white space "under" tableView subview when tableView scrolled to its content limits

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableViewCell as a subview in a custom view controller. It works great except that when it scrolls to its top or bottom of its contentSize limit, it "keeps going" and leaves some white space exposed behind it. This is particularly irritating because I do have a UIView covering the entire screen behind the tableView, and that view is set to a non-white color. I also added a subview exactly underlaying the tableview with the same background color, again attempting to block the white. I also set the UIApplication Window background color to a non white color. None of this worked.

I would have thought that even if my TableView bounces around its origin frame, the "exposed" view should match the underlying view rather than be white. How can I fix my tableView so that it retains all its scroll properties but doesn't reveal white when it bounces around at the end of a scroll?

Here is a screen shot of the effect. The white appears the tableViewHeader and below a UISCrollView that occupies the top of the screen. This appears when I scroll the tableView all the way to one extreme. The white space appears at the bottom rather than the top of the tableView if I scroll all the way to the other end.

[image: unwanted white space screen shot]

Here's the relevant code, quite vanilla I think:

```
@interface JudgeViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate,  UIViewControllerRestoration, UIScrollViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic) UITableView *tableView;
@end
```

functions to set tableViewCells

```
#pragma mark - tableview appearance and actions

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    StatsViewController *svc  = [[StatsViewController alloc] init];
    svc.user = self.object.answerUser[indexPath.row];
    svc.fromJudge = YES;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:svc animated:YES];

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.object.answerArray count];
}



-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    UILabel *label = nil;
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if(cell ==nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [label setLineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
        [label setMinimumFontSize:SMALL_FONT_SIZE];
        [label setNumberOfLines:0];
        [label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:SMALL_FONT_SIZE]];
        [label setTag:1];

        // [[label layer] setBorderWidth:2.0f];


        [[cell contentView] addSubview:label];

    }


    CGFloat width = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
    CGFloat height = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;


    NSString *text = self.object.answerArray[indexPath.row];
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(.8*CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN)*2, 200000.0f);
    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:SMALL_FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint];

    if(!label)
        label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];

    [label setText:text];
    [label setFrame:CGRectMake(CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN, CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN, .8*CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN)*2, MAX(size.height, 44.0f))];

    UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button1.frame = CGRectMake(.85*width, label.frame.size.height/2-2*CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN, .12*width, 20);
    [button1 setTitle:@"UP" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button1.titleLabel.font =[UIFont systemFontOfSize:SMALLEST_FONT_SIZE];
    [button1 setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(upVoteA:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:button1];
    [cell.contentView bringSubviewToFront:button1];

    UIButton *button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button2.frame = CGRectMake(.85*width, label.frame.size.height/2+2*CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN, .12*width, 20);
    [button2 setTitle:@"DOWN" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button2.titleLabel.font =[UIFont systemFontOfSize:SMALLEST_FONT_SIZE];
    [button2 setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(downVoteA:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    CGFloat moduloResult = indexPath.row % 2;
    if(moduloResult>0)
    {
       cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0.647 blue:0 alpha:.6];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0.647 blue:0 alpha:.4];
    }
    cell.opaque = NO;
    cell.alpha = 0.2;

    [cell.contentView addSubview:button2];
    [cell.contentView bringSubviewToFront:button2];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    return cell;
}

-(void)keyboardToJudge
{

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.row < [self.object.answerArray count])
    {
    NSString *text = self.object.answerArray[indexPath.row];
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(.8*CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN)*2, 200000.0f);
    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE-2.0f] constrainedToSize:constraint];
    CGFloat height = MAX(size.height, 44.0f);
    return height + (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN)*2;
    }
    else
    {
        return 200.0f;
    }

}
```

functions setting out layout:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
...among other things setting up top scroll view (top part of view with gray background and orange text)...
   if(self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height>0)
    {
    self.scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 5, width, height*SCROLL_VIEW_OFFSET)];
    }
    else
    {
    self.scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, statusBarHeight+5, width, height*SCROLL_VIEW_OFFSET)];
    }
    self.scroll.backgroundColor = BACKGROUND_COLOR;
    self.scroll.contentSize =CGSizeMake(width, .5*height);
    self.scroll.delegate = self;
    self.scroll.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(30, 0, 30, 0);
    [self.scroll setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];



...adding buttons to self.scroll...

    [self.view addSubview:self.scroll];

....


    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;

    self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, _width, _height*.1)];
    self.tableView.tableFooterView.backgroundColor = BACKGROUND_COLOR;


    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, _width, _height*.1)];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView.backgroundColor = BACKGROUND_COLOR;

....tableView hidden state is changed to yes in another function if row count is zero but not usually...
    self.tableView.hidden = NO; 
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
...
}
```

Finally, I also call :

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

after reloading data from a webserver and depending on the results either set the tableView to hidden or not (not hidden if there are results to display). That should be every line of code that touches the tableView subview.

Comment: if you could post related screenshot & code , that will help alot.

Comment: @pawan Thanks for your comment. I thought the code was quite plain and long so I skipped it, but now I have pasted it along with a screen shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your `viewDidLoad`

```
[self.tableView setBackgroundColor:BACKGROUND_COLOR];
```

Set the background color of your `tableView` and you'll be fine

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I just tried this, but the white space is still there.

Comment: OOps, my original suggestion was close, but off ... set the background of the UITableView and you'll be OK.  I've edited my answer

Comment: It's defined in a header file included in this file. I tried with [UIColor redColor] and can see this behind the top scroll view but not behind the tableView. The white space is still there. But you made me think that maybe the tableView.backgroundColor had to be set separately from the cell colors and header/footer colors, and that did the trick. Thank you.

Comment: We found it simultaneously! If you want to post the answer I will be happy to credit you. Thanks again. NM, I see you edited your answer, so I'll check it off.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
self.scroll.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(30, 0, 30, 0);
```

To this:

```
self.scroll.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

You are adding a footer to your `tableview` with that line. The following image is from the IOS dev Library
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but this also had no effect. I put this in to manage view overlay with a navBar above and a tabBar below the viewer. Also the white space peeks out at both the top and bottom of the tableView, just depends on which direction I have scrolled.

Comment: In fact, I just deleted that line altogether - it was leftover from dealing with overlay issues but didn't do what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Set the table view estimate to 0 (Uncheck Automatic) in the size inspector